# selected option text not showing in semantic ui dropdown field

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tsx

I am using React semantic UI. I am rendering a dropdown. I have written code such that, once an option is selected, the options text is shown in the field. But when I select an option from the dropdown, the selected value's text is not displayed, rather it shows an empty field.

Here is my dropdown code:

```
options = [
  { key:"a", value: 1, name: 'uni',  text: "first"},
  { key:"b", value: 2, name: 'duo',  text: 'second'},
  { key:"c", value: 3, name: 'tri',  text: ' third'},
  { key:"d", value: 4, name: 'quart', text: 'fourth'},
  { key:"e", value: 5, name: 'cinq',  text: 'sixth'},
  { key:"f", value: 6, name: 'dernier', text: 'last'}
];

 const  handleDropDownSelect = (event, data) => {
    onChangeValue(data.value)

  };
  const Dropdown = () => (
return(
      <Dropdown
          placeholder = abc"
          fluid
          selection
          options={options}
          onChange={handleDropDownSelect}

      />)

 <DropDownContainer className="Dropdown">
            <Dropdown />
 </DropDownContainer>
```

`onChangeValue` is a function I am using in a different component where I get the value from this dropdown and update other components. So the issue is, when I select an option, the text should be shown in the dropdown field, not left blanc

Comment: You need to share how you implement `Dropdown` component too. That would help in finding where your problem is

Comment: i just called the dropdown where i needed it to be implemented like this  <DropDownContainer className="Column, Dropdown">
            <Dropdown />
 </DropDownContainer>

Comment: You don't use any library for DropDown component?

Comment: i use semantic ui

Comment: I tried an example, it seems to work fine https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-txevw3?file=/example.js. What else is missing in this example?

Comment: it somehow worked when i define the dropdown in the return itself  but if i define the dropdown ousite the return as a component, then render the component in the return, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

it worked, i had to edit the options array